# Jquery UI Sortable - setting items option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

guys!
I have a problem. I need to initialize my sortable() with items 'li:not(.someclass)'.
If I set:

```
$('ul').sortable({ items: 'li:not(.someclass)' });
```

everything works fine. But if I try:

```
$('ul').sortable().sortable('option', 'items', 'li:not(.someclass)');
```

It doesn't work. Why option 'items' exists if it doesn't work correctly or what is correct way to set up items through options?

Try examples [here](http://jsbin.com/ejakof/edit#source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cancel (Couldn't get items working) - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8kmcP/)

```
$('ul').sortable();
$("ul").sortable("option", 'cancel', 'ul > li.last');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everything is fine!
Is any way to set items, not cancel (in general case)?

Comment: I tried it also, but doesnt seem to work. probably need to check its an issue. Cause i see multiple threads on it.